# Using Square Bracket as Multiple Delimiter In Shell

Tags: shell, unix, aix

i have a log like below :

```
19.11.05 16:58:07.574 [     shc:7471262]
```

I want to parse it using square bracket as a multiple delimiter with the colon (":") character as well

```
awk -F '[:]' '{print $4}'
```

it considers the ":" as the only delimiter ([ and ] aren't counted)

Comment: What do you want the command to print?

Comment: Maybe something like `cut -d \[ -f 2 <logfile | cut -d : -f 1`

Comment: Counting `$4`, did you count colon (`:`) between `HH:MM:SS`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to double echap bracket:

```
awk -F'[\\]:\\[]' '{print $4}' <logfile
```

May do what you want.

Or

```
cut -d \[ -f 2 <logfile | cut -d : -f 1
```